# LSTM with Keras: Input 'ref' of 'Assign' Op requires l-value input

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I want to run an lstm with keras. I have 5 classes to classify, encoded as one hot labels.

Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(10000, 32))
model.add(LSTM(64, dropout_W=0.2, dropout_U=0.2))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics='acc')

model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=10,validation_split=0.2)
```

But i get the following error:

> TypeError: Input 'ref' of 'Assign' Op requires l-value input

Here is the error log:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         6 n_epochs = 10
>         7 
>   ----> 8 history = model.fit(train_encoded, train_labels_lstm, batch_size=bs, nb_epoch=n_epochs,validation_split=0.2)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in fit(self, x, y,
>   batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split,
>   validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch,
>   steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
>       961                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
>       962                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
>   --> 963                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
>       964 
>       965     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x,
>   y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split,
>   validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch,
>   steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)    1680         else:
>   1681             ins = x + y + sample_weights
>   -> 1682         self._make_train_function()    1683         f = self.train_function    1684
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in
>   _make_train_function(self)
>       988                     training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(
>       989                         params=self._collected_trainable_weights,
>   --> 990                         loss=self.total_loss)
>       991                 updates = self.updates + training_updates + self.metrics_updates
>       992                 # Gets loss and metrics. Updates weights at each call.
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in
>   wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>        89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
>        90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
>   ---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>        92         wrapper._original_function = func
>        93         return wrapper
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py in get_updates(self,
>   loss, params)
>       255             # update accumulator
>       256             new_a = self.rho * a + (1. - self.rho) * K.square(g)
>   --> 257             self.updates.append(K.update(a, new_a))
>       258             new_p = p - lr * g / (K.sqrt(new_a) + self.epsilon)
>       259
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in
>   update(x, new_x)
>       961         The variable `x` updated.
>       962     """
>   --> 963     return tf.assign(x, new_x)
>       964 
>       965
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_state_ops.py
>   in assign(ref, value, validate_shape, use_locking, name)
>        45   result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Assign", ref=ref, value=value,
>        46                                 validate_shape=validate_shape,
>   ---> 47                                 use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
>        48   return result
>        49
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py
>   in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
>       615             raise TypeError(
>       616                 "Input '%s' of '%s' Op requires l-value input" %
>   --> 617                 (input_name, op_type_name))
>       618           input_types.extend(types)
>       619         else:
>
> TypeError: Input 'ref' of 'Assign' Op requires l-value input

What should I change?